# I want to list someone 's git commit ,but I don't know the git command formate of since or after

Tags: git, processbuilder

When I execute this git command: `git rev-list --since=2015-03-01`, it always says

> Invalid object name 'usage'.

I don't know the format of since or after.
I'm using Java ProcessBuilder to execute the command.
Any help appreciated!

The code:

```java
command=new String[] {"git", "rev-list", "--since=2015-06-22", "--pretty=oneline"};
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error about `usage` because you're using arguments that are not valid for `rev-list`, and git will print a usage summary as a result. The first word it gets back is `usage`, which it is complaining about.

```
$ git rev-list --since=2015-06-22 --pretty=oneline
usage: git rev-list [OPTION] <commit-id>... [ -- paths... ]
  limiting output:
    --max-count=<n>
    --max-age=<epoch>
```

... and so on.

Based on your current attempt, I gather you are trying to find commits after a certain date, and return them one per line. Since you are using `rev-list` instead of `log`, you probably want a list of commit objects, not full log entries.

The main problem with your command is that `rev-list` expects a commit ID or other reference as its starting point, and you aren't supplying one. That's easy, just point it to `HEAD`.

This will give you the commit IDs from HEAD back to the specified date.

```
git rev-list --since=2015-06-22 HEAD
```

Or specified in the syntax you are using for Java,

```java
command=new String[] {"git", "rev-list", "--since=2015-06-22", "HEAD"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command -

```
git log --author="NAME" --since="2015-06-22"
```

Add `--oneline` to get only commit hash followed by commit message.

Note: --after and --since options are synonymous.

Comment: yeah, I added "--pretty=oneline" before ,and I have already tried --since="2016-4-5 01:30:00",but it still said Invalid object name 'usage'.

Comment: I should add --all ,then add --since and specific time.Thanks!